# playing 3D rotated video on android

Tags: android, android-videoview

I'm trying find a way to play a video in a view while rotating it on Android 2.2. I'm not talking about 90 degrees rotation, I'm talking about 3D rotations.

I see that starting from API level 14 there is View.SetRotation/X/Y but I want to use API LEVEL 8.

I've tried creating my own video view by extending VideoView, create a custom matrix and set:

```
canvas.setMatrix(matrix);
```

in onDraw(Canvas) and dispatchDraw(Canvas), but this didn't make a difference. My video is playing completely flat.

Any idea how I can do this?

Here you can see some examples to what I would like to achieve:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDXxPQEDegY

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OBoCrWrabs4

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [NineOldAndroids](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids).

> Android library for using the Honeycomb animation API on all versions
>   of the platform back to 1.0

Comment: I understand this library is "all about animating values over time, and assigning those values to target objects and properties". I don't see how this can help if canvas.setMatrix(matrix) doesn't have any effect. Which property should I try to "animate" in order to get 3D transformation for a VideoView? Thanks!

Comment: You wrote, "I see that starting from API level 14 there is View.SetRotation/X/Y but I want to use API LEVEL 8." -- NineOldAndroids gives you access to the latest animation APIs on any SDK version.

Answer (score 0):

In the examples you have mentioned, no one is rotating videos.
That is a simple AR app which recognizes an image provided as the "marker" in the app bundle itself.
When it recognizes the image a set action is performed, that can be playing video or doing anything you want (possible in Android :)).
I have done this in past and will try to fetch some snippets for you.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the recognition process. In these examples, after the app recognizes the "marker", it plays a video in a perspective view. I'm only trying to do that, but I haven't managed to do so yet.